# Android phone: How to simply open an application without installation (as it is already installed) using Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium-android, java-client

Scenarios to automate is:

I installed an application and logged in successfully. There is an "App Lock" feature which closes the application.
I clicked on App Lock and application is closed. Now, **I need to open application again without installing and login.**

In short scenario is like:
1. Install and login to application.
2. Close the application.
3. Reopen the application.

**Expected result:**
Application should be opened and post login screen should be displayed

**Actual:**
Used below capability but application is reinstalled and Sign-Up (prelogin) screen is displayed

I search for answer and found below capability but it didn't worked.

```
    File appDir = new File(appDirr);
    File app = new File(appDir, "appName");
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung Galaxy S8");
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "appPackageName");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", "appActivityName");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    appiumDriver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
```

Please let me know how can I automate this scenario.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove following capability:

```
caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());//This installs the application
```

Use this method:

```
appiumDriver.activateApp(appPackage);
```

You should know your application `appPackage` and `appActivityName`.

[appPackage and appActivityName](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/)

Comment: "startActivity" is throwing error at my end. Error is "The method startActivity(Activity) is undefined for the type AppiumDriver" and java client version is 7.0.0

Comment: Updated the answer, please use the capability and just call `.launch_app()`

Comment: caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath()) still deteled.

Comment: I tried adding these 4 lines DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities(); caps.setCapability("appPackage", appPackage);                       
caps.setCapability("appActivity", appActivity);                       
appiumDriver.launchApp();           
but still it took me on signup screen

Comment: `.launchApp();` it will bring to main activity (home your app), I think you want back to the last activity, it will achieve by `startActivity`

Comment: can we use .startActivity in Java Client 7.0.0 because it is throwing error for me "The method startActivity(Activity) is undefined for the type AppiumDriver"

Comment: is it possible that your driver's initials have been changed? if yes, then try change `AppiumDriver<MobileElement> appiumDriver` to `AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> appiumDriver;`

Comment: hey frianH, simply this appiumDriver.activateApp(appPackage); one like code worked for me. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

```
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");
```

Use this `capability`. Your app is not installed every test.

If you want to close the app when run the test so you should `driver.closeApp().`
And open the app again use to `driver.launchApp()` method.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but  capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true); this capability didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Appium to do anything with the application you can consider setting `autoLaunch` [Desired Capability](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Capabilities) to `false`

> `autoLaunch` - Initializing the app under test automatically. Appium does not install/launch the app under test if this is false. Defaults to true

When you want to kick off the application you can use [AndroidDriver.launchApp()](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/InteractsWithApps.html#launchApp--) function

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following approach

```
1. Install the application and login successfully. lock app using "App Lock"  

2. Open application again without installing by using adb command to launch the activity like below example
```

***adb shell am start -n com.example.package(Put your package name here)/.MainActivity (Activity to be launched )***

Comment: We have build a custom method to execute adb code which we use,

Comment: actions.executeADBCommands("adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "deviceName": "Android",
  "automationName": "Appium",
  "appPackage": "com.bla.automation",
  "appActivity": "com.bla.splash.SplashScreenActivity",
  "noReset": true,
  "fullReset": false,
  "dontStopAppOnReset": false,
  "autoLaunch": false
}
```